# angular 2 - Cells copied from Excel contains new line on (input) area

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I have a strange behaviour on *IE11*. When I copy cells from an Excel document and past it to a search input element, I get only the last cell, since the cells were copied with the new line. On *chrome* it works.

[image]

I have tried to change the result on the paste event and force the change, but again it works on chrome and not on *IE11*

```
<input [formControl]="search" 
       type="text" 
       [(ngModel)]="filterText"  
       (ngModelChange)="onChange(input)" 
       (paste)= "onPaste($event)" 
       class="form-control"
       (keyup.enter)="onRefreshPage()">
```

on my componant I use a regex to replace the `/n` with *empty space*

```
    onPaste(inputEvent) {
    const content = inputEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain').replace(/\s|\n/g, ' ');
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.filterText = content;
    }, 500);

    inputEvent.stopPropagation();
}

onChange(input) {
    this.filterText = input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but in IE11 `clipboardData` is not property of `inputEvent`, but rather property of `window`.

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/795769/clipboarddata-should-be-a-member-of-the-event-and-not-of-window

Try to get the content like this:

```
onPaste(inputEvent) {
    const data = inputEvent.clipboardData || (window as any).clipboardData;
    const content = data.getData('text/plain').replace(/\s|\n/g, ' ');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I already tried window, but I get eslint error: clipboardData not a property of window. The window is an interface in lib es6

Comment: just cast it to `any` when accessing it: `const data = (window as any).clipboardData;`

Comment: Does not work, I get only the first cell copied. On chrome works